# IPv6 only server through Cloudflare gateway

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, dns-hosting, cloudflare

In the past, one could use an IPv6 server through sixxs.net gateway. Now the service is gone.

However, I found  there is a [free Cloudflare gateway](https://www.cloudflare.com/ipv6/). I assume the IPv6 server is to be associated to a domain or subdomain  through an AAAA record. I don't think this is possible otherwise.

However, Cloudflare docs are full of marketing hype and I don't actually understand if an *IPv4-only client will be able to access IPv6-only servers* through them (for ssh or for hosting a webserver).

Can you give me an answer, please?

Comment: Cloudflare provides a free service level. Any reason why you haven't just tried it?

Comment: Exactly what protocol are you trying to use? Your question is tagged DNS but asks about SSH and HTTP. I doubt you can do SSH with the free service because in order to work with a non-modified SSH client it requires a separate IPv4 address per backend.

Comment: @SanderSteffann: You are not totally wrong) However, before making the tests (so getting the IPv6,  setting up the server, registering it with Cloudflare), I wanted to probe if someone had some previous knowledge/experience, considering how common Cloudfare is. What for setup everything if I know in advance it would not work as (I understand is) advertised?

Comment: @kasperd: SSH and HTTP are the desired services. I mentioned DNS, because I had in mind a managed DNS provider routing requests from an IPv4 client to an IPv6 server. If the gateway service does not provide a DNS too, how can it be reached by an IPv4-only client?

Comment: @antonio DNS is difficult to get right even when no proxy is involved. Proxying DNS traffic is complicated, and I don't know if anybody tried to do it. It's something I have wanted to implement myself, but I haven't had the time. But do you really need DNS traffic to be proxied? Is there any reason you can't have your domain hosted on authoritative servers with dual stack connectivity?

Comment: @kasperd: There are now some VPS offers that give an IPv4 address and a bunch of IPv6 addresses. I'd like to use the main IPv4 for the primary services and one or more IPv6's for secondary services (backup/recovery/testing).
To make IPv6's worth using (and buy) they should be reachable from an IPv4 client too. A DNS provider which could route IPv4 requests to IPv6 seems one way to obtain this. If DNS+gateway service cost < new IPv4, buying a bunch of IPv6 makes sense.

Comment: @antonio Why not just run a single authoritative DNS server which listens on all addresses assigned to the host? The zones will be in different zone files and a DNS server has no problem serving many zones from different files.

Comment: @Well, mainly for performance reasons, a provider (like Cloudflare) gives features in terms of load-balancing and optimisation not  attainable by adding an authoritative DNS as the n-th service to a VPS. Plus, they give some peace of mind in terms of DDoS protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cloudflare support IPv6 addresses to your origin server, and will accept both IPv4 and IPv6 from clients.

[image]

I am currently using a Vultr server which is $2.5 per month, and only support IPv6

Comment: Does that support any other protocols than HTTP? Can it do SSH, DNS, and SMTP? (The question mentions SSH and HTTP and is tagged DNS)

Comment: I think it's only for HTTP on ports 80/443. The question says "SSH or HTTP" - this works for HTTP. If they meant "SSH AND HTTP", then the question should be updated. I use VULTR Console to access the console (not SSH). I also use Putty on another cloud machine which has both IPv4 and IPv6 to connect via SSH.